# ListView item gets destroyed while moving to other activity

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, dynamic-list

My first activity contains a listview with textviews  in each cell and uses a custom adapter. So if you click on any of the items, it will open up a form activity containing textfields. The user can fill up the details and once they press the save form button the details appear on the listview. Now I am trying to add items to the list dynamically. I have created a button which when clicked adds a new instance item so that more users can register the same way. I have been able to implement these functions. However, my problem now is when i click on the newly added item and go to the form activity and click save, i am not able to see the newly added entry after i come back to the listview activity.All I see is the first entry alone. So i am guessing it gets destroyed as soon as i leave the activity. How to ensure all newly added items are not destroyed when i keep moving between these two activities.

Here is my code of the ListView Activity:

```
public class FormTableActivity extends Activity {

    private PassengerListAdapter adapter;
    Button add_passenger;
    String mrzdata,ic_data,name_data;
    SharedPreferences nPref;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.final_display_listview);

        nPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);


        mrzdata = nPref.getString("MRZ", "");
        name_data = nPref.getString("resultData", "");

        ic_data = nPref.getString("icdata", "");

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.custom_list);

        adapter = new PassengerListAdapter(this);
        adapter.add(new CustomerDetails(ic_data, name_data, mrzdata));

        add_passenger = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_user);
        add_passenger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

//                mrzdata = "";
//                name_data = "";
//                ic_data = "";
                adapter.add(new CustomerDetails(ic_data, name_data, mrzdata));


            }
        });


        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {


                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), FirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: Your problem would be more clear if you would add some of your code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to save these newly added items somewhere , e.g. to a SQLite database and retrieve them on create to populate the listview

You can see here if You want, the code is commented ,
here I have a listview with custom adapter with two items
the feed's name and it's url

i add URL and name using a text input dialog (with two edit text), save to DB, and retrieve them on create to populate the listview
https://github.com/enricocid/iven-feed-reader/blob/master-as/project/app/src/main/java/com/iven/lfflfeedreader/mainact/ListActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass data between Intent is

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), your_list_view_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("String_Key", data1);
//data1 could be an array of string where you have hold the values previously
startActivity(intent);
```

now on your list_view_activity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String [] value = extras.getString("String_Key");
}
```

This way you won't get any exception but you get to populate your listView if there is data.

Another way to get data is via SharedPreference but I won't recommend it as it increases the size of the app.